# BF-F8HP: "Radio did not respond" when trying to use CHIRP

Tags: baofeng, radio-programming

I'm trying to program my Baofeng bf-f8hp with the chirp software, but as I have to do, "Download From Radio", after I choose the appropriate maker, product and model, all I get is an error message which reads, "An Error has occured: The Radio did not respond."
I've unplugged all, restarted computer and plugged all back in, turned on radio, same result.
Ideas?

Comment: For me, experiencing this same issue, I resolved it by power cycling the radio after it was plugged into the computer, but before attempting to connect CHIRP to the radio. And now it works quite nicely.

Answer (score 6):

For me I didn't have my radio cable fully pushed into my radio. It took some extra pressure and then it snapped in place. I had to press harder than expected.

Comment: Hello Ray, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @rclocher3 Thanks, I should be taking my ham technician test next week!  I'm excited to try out my radio :)

Comment: Excellent!  Good luck!

Comment: This ended up being the problem for me. I thought for sure I'd pushed the cable all the way in, but I hadn't. It really does require a firm little push!

Comment: Ha ha, this fixed it for me to.

Answer (score 5):

The most common error is not selecting the correct COM port for the virtualized USB cable.

Comment: or tty port, if you're using Linux, BSD or Mac OS.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the USB programming cables are not supported by the new Windows drivers that are installed automatically -specifically those with the Prolific PL-2303 USB chip set. You 'can' sometimes use them by downloading and installing an older driver. Better to get a proper cable though.

[CHIRP Cable Guide](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/CableGuide)

Answer (score 3):

Another common error is related to their quality control.  I had a unit (UV-5R+) that wouldn't work, like that.

Contacted the seller and they sent me a new "body" - and it worked.

So in a case where you are really stuck, I suggest you contact the seller.

Answer (score 1):

the most common problem I have encountered with folks I've helped ... the connector is not all the way seated in the radio.

Answer (score 0):

The USB -> Baofeng cable can be difficult to seat properly in the radio.  If it isn't making good contact, it can affect whether CHRIP will function correctly or not.

You might check the connection and connect your cable with the radio more tightly.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  In the future, try to include more detail in your answers.  It's fine for them to be short, but including some explanation or reasoning can go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while troubleshooting my own problem. Chirp on Arch Linux. There were over 32 COM ports labeled tty0-tty32 that were all throwing errors. Here is what I had to do:

1. Run chirp as root so that I did not run into permission issues using the COM ports. You can get around this by adding your user to the dialout group, but as I did not have this group, I just run as root.
2. Use a USB port that plugs directly into the motherboard, not the front panel, since those function as a hub.
3. Use a legacy 2.0 (not 3.0) USB port
4. Reboot the machine with the USB cable plugged in (not sure if this step is necessary, but I did it during my testing).
5. Now at the very bottom of the list there was a /dev/ttyUSB0 that was not there before.
6. Select a compatible radio from the list. In my case, using Radioddity UV-5RX3 for Baofeng UV-S9PLUS

Answer (score 0):

After wrestling with this issue for a number of days, and trying every possible remedy, I finally figured it out. The USB connection on the Baofeng cable loosens over time, or is just poorly manufactured, so what you need to do is hold it in the correct position where CHIRP is communicating with the radio. You'll know when you've got it. BAM!!! Works like it's supposed too!!

I just programmed four UV-5Rs and two BF-F9V2+... that weren't responding before.

Good luck... and I hope this works for you.